# Sometimes empty application search results in Unity

Tags: 11.04, unity

I saw a bunch of other questions here asking about the search results of Unity, but mine is slightly different. Sometimes, when I *search for an application in Unity*, no search results come up for the application. For any application for that matter. What I usually end up doing is restarting the computer or logging out then back in.

When I click on "More Apps", there are no apps listed there unless I re-login.

What's a better way to refresh the index (?) without re-logging in?

Comment: Are you using 11.10 or 11.04? Please add that to the tags atleast.

Comment: The Unity Shell can be restarted by `unity --replace`

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I forget there's a new beta for Ubuntu. Thanks, that should work next time it happens!